# python:How to extract a word before and after the match using regex

Tags: regex, python-3.x

Cosnider the follwing data as sample

> input_corpus = "this is an example.\n I am trying to extract it.\n"

I am trying to extract exactly 2 words before and after .\n with the following code

```
for m in re.finditer('(?:\S+\s+){2,}[\.][\n]\s*(?:\S+\b\s*){0,2}',input_corpus):
   print(m)
```

Expected output :

```
an example. I am
extract it.
```

Actual output: Nothing gets captured

Can someone point me what is wrong with the regex.

Comment: There are two issues: 1) the first `\s+` requires a space before `.` and your strings has none, 2) `\b` is not treated as word boundary but as a BACKSPACE char since your string literal is not raw. Use `r` prefix. `r"(?:\S+\s*){2,}\.\n\s*(?:\S+\b\s*){0,2}"` matches the whole string, but is ineffecient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use this regex:

```
r'(?:^|\S+\s+\S+)\n(?:\s*\S+\s+\S+|$)'
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/NzGOiZ/1)

**Code:**

```
>>> input_corpus = "this is an example.\n I am trying to extract it.\n"
>>> print re.findall(r'(?:^|\S+\s+\S+)\n(?:\s*\S+\s+\S+|$)', input_corpus)
['an example.\n I am', 'extract it.\n']
```

**Details:**

- `(?:^|\S+\s+\S+)`: Match preceding 2 words or line start
- `\n`: Match a new line
- `(?:\s*\S+\s+\S+|$)`: Match next 2 words or line end

Comment: I think OP tried to quantify the number of words after a newline matched (see `(?:\S+\b\s*){0,2}`), so `(?:\S+\s+\S+)\n(?:\s*\S+(?:\s+\S+)?)?` should be closer.

Comment: Yes possible but OP also wrote: *I am trying to extract exactly 2 words before and after .\n*

Answer (score 0):

A non-regex way:

```
sen = 'Beneﬁciary Name / John Hunter Alex'
sub_sen = 'John Hunter'

def sentence_proximity(sentence, ner_string):
  sen_l = sen.split()
  sub_sen_l = sub_sen.split()

  start_idx = 0
  end_idx = 0
  search_string = ''

  if len(sub_sen_l) < 2:
    print('single word')
    curr_idx = sen_l.index(sub_sen_l[0])
    if curr_idx >= 0:
      start_idx = curr_idx - 1
    else: 
      start_idx = curr_idx

    if curr_idx < len(sen_l) - 1:
      end_idx = curr_idx + 2
    else:
      end_idx = curr_idx + 1

  else:
    print('multiple words')
    curr_start_idx = sen_l.index(sub_sen_l[0])
    if curr_start_idx >= 0:
      start_idx = curr_start_idx - 1
    else: 
      start_idx = curr_start_idx

    curr_end_idx = sen_l.index(sub_sen_l[-1])
    if curr_end_idx < len(sen_l) - 1:
      end_idx = curr_end_idx + 2
    else:
      end_idx = curr_end_idx + 1

  search_string = ' '.join(sen_l[start_idx:end_idx])
  print(f'Generated string: {search_string}')

sentence_proximity(sen, sub_sen)
```